# FormatDateTime ошибка при обработке списка файлов

Tags: delphi

Обрабатываю список файлов в каталоге. И собранный результат, со всех файлов, сохраняю в один файл Out. Также, к имени файла, добавляю дату создания файла через **FormatDateTime('hh_mm_ss_zzz', Time)**.

**Самое интересное что если с кода убрать FormatDateTime('hh_mm_ss_zzz', Time) то он работает идеально.** А если оставить то постоянно ошибка **"Файл не найден"**. В чем же тогда вопрос и **почему такая проблема возникает в коде ?**

**Опубликовал нужные части кода что бы можно было быстро разобраться:**

```
Var
  File1, File2: TextFile;
  S: string;
  v: Integer;
  file_list: TStringList;
  flname1, flname2: string;
  p: string;

begin

  file_list := TStringList.Create;
  // Извлекаем все разширения файла
  p := '*' + ExtractFileExt(flname1);

  // Ищем файлы в папке используя функцию f_Search_1 (Путь к папке в Edit1)
  f_Search_1(Edit1.Text + '\', p, file_list);

  // Обрабатываю все файлы в цикле
  for v := 0 to file_list.Count - 1 do
  begin

    flname1 := file_list.Strings[v];
    AssignFile(File1, flname1);
    reset(File1);

    // Вот тут если убрать FormatDateTime то работает код ИДЕАЛЬНО!
    AssignFile(File2, ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'Out' +
      FormatDateTime('hh_mm_ss_zzz', Time));

    if v = 0 then
      rewrite(File2)
    else
      append(File2);

    // Далее идет построчная обработка файла:
    while not Eof(File1) do
    begin
      ReadLn(File1, S);

      if (Pos('авто компрессор', S) > 0) then
        writeln(File2, S);

    end;

  end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы же для каждого файла из списка создаете новое имя выходного файла, так как имя файла формируете с использованием текущего времени с точностью до миллисекунды при каждой итерации цикла, при этом выходной файл создаете только для первого файла из списка, для остальных же дескриптор связывается, а сам файл не создается.

Так как, вам нужно содержимое всех файлов из списка влить в один выходной файл, то нужно формирование имени выходного файла с указанием времени создания вынести из цикла обработки файлов. И вообще само создание файла также вынести из цикла, а внутри цикла уже только дописывать в него.

Comment: Спасибо Вам Vasil Baymurzin, я чего то сам запутался. Все сработало.